# Why does Lydia prefer an Ebony helmet over a Dragonplate one?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Lydia's preferred armor loadout?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49520/what-is-lydias-preferred-armor-loadout)

I have made Lydia a full set of Dragonplate armor, however whenever I have her "pack mule" an ebony helmet, she equips the latter. Neither helmet has been smithed beyond their standard defensive values (26 and 25, respectively.) Why is this the case? Can I do anything about it?

Comment: probably because dragonplate is fugly :P

Comment: Whoops, wrong question to comment on: Anywho.. I can not find the references for this any longer but I do believe Lydia has (had?) a bug where she would prefer to equip the more Expensive items as opposed to the higher Rated items. Since I can not find the references to link to however, this is just a comment.. +1 to yx's comment though as well ;)

Comment: This should be answered by your [other](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49520/what-is-lydias-preferred-armor-loadout) question.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the armor stats.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the order of the helmets based on the inventory? That's the only thing I can think of.